# How to drop factor levels while scraping data off US Census HTML site

Tags: r, scrape, census

Thank you in advance for your help. On the US Census website (below), I am looking for an element in the 6th row, 3rd column of the 4th table.

Here's the code I am writing:

```
complete_URL <- "http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/01/01011.html"
temp_TBL <- readHTMLTable(complete_URL, which=4)
business_number_vector <- temp_TBL[6,3]
print(business_number_vector)
```

What I get is:

```
[1] 417
Levels: 417
```

What I'd like is:

```
[1] 417
```

Thank you again so much for your help!

Comment: do: `as.numeric(as.character(temp_TBL[6,3]))`. It seems to be a `factor` variable.

Comment: Arun, you are so awesome.  Thank you so much.  I can't tell you how grateful I am.  I've been scratching my head on this for a while now.

Comment: No problem. `factor` gives that feeling to everyone at the beginning. Remember, the `as.character` is important before `as.numeric`. You can post it as an answer and accept it when you can so that the question remains answered.

Comment: `as.numeric(levels(business_number_vector)[business_number_vector])` would work as well and is closer to the way that is recommended in the help documentation for `factor`

Comment: Thank you Dason.  I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually R-FAQ 7.10:

You should be able to see the FAQ with your R-help() system. On my machine it is set up as html:

```
http://127.0.0.1:23603/doc/manual/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f
```

> 7.10 How do I convert factors to numeric?
>
> It may happen that when reading numeric data into R (usually, when reading in a file), they come in as factors. If f is such a factor object, you can use
>
> as.numeric(as.character(f))
>   to get the numbers back. More efficient, but harder to remember, is
>
> as.numeric(levels(f))[as.integer(f)]
>   In any case, do not call as.numeric() or their likes directly for the task at hand (as as.numeric() or unclass() give the internal codes).

Comment: There should be one question tagged r-faq for each issue, I guess, not three (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950672 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381154 are dupes you also tagged). Also, this is a link-only answer (not encouraged on SO). Finally, my understanding is that the r-faq tag is for questions that are frequently asked on SO, not for anything that is answered in the R-FAQ doc. (I'm not saying this doesn't fall into both categories; just saying.)

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. It's a reference to material that is on the user's machine by virtual if installing the R package. It's NOT a "link" to a web address.

Comment: My first sentence and the "Finally" sentence are related -- if there are dupes, mark them as such; and also economize on use of the [tag:r-faq] tag by only applying it to the dupe target and not its dupes. Re it being a link, yeah, technically it is not, but it has the same feature of not answering the question in the body of the answer. First, you could give proper instructions to reach the FAQ (since it's not obvious); and second, you could quote whatever it is you think is relevant there. Anyway, we can talk about this in the R chat room if there's still confusion or disagreement.

Comment: Personally, I think people should be reading the R-FAQ ... cover to cover as it were. So I think posting the entire text of a FAQ is a violation of `fortunes::fortune("WTFM")`   #This is all documented in TFM. Those who WTFM don't want to have to WTFM again on the mailing list. RTFM.
   -- Barry Rowlingson
      R-help (October 2003)  ... but maybe that's just one man's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Arun and Dason provided these answers:

Arun recommended:

```
complete_URL <- "http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/01/01011.html"
temp_TBL <- readHTMLTable(complete_URL, which=4)
business_number_vector <- as.numeric(as.character(temp_TBL[6,3]))
print(business_number_vector)
```

see line 3, where `as.numeric(as.character())` helped big-time!

Dason recommended:

```
complete_URL <- "http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/01/01011.html"
temp_TBL <- readHTMLTable(complete_URL, which=4)
business_number_vector <- temp_TBL[6,3]
business_number_vector <- as.numeric(levels(business_number_vector)[business_number_vector])
print(business_number_vector)
```

see line 4 where `as.numeric(levels(business_number_vector)[business_number_vector])` also helped big-time!