# How to get the levels number in R?

Tags: r

I used a `as.data.frame(table(something_to_count))`, and get result like:

```
    Var1  Freq
1     20  2970
2     30  1349
3     40   322
4     50  1009
```

I just want the `$Var1` value, but if I write `d[1,]$Var1` or `d[1,1]`, I always get these things:

```
1] 20
305 Levels: 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 150 160 170 190 200 ... 4120
```

And when I try to output the value, it is always not 20, but 1. And `as.number()` also can only return 1. How can I literally get the Var1 value as it is instead of getting the id of the row? Also, when the outputs are levels numbers? What is wrong?

Comment: It's a factor.  You can use `as.numeric(as.character(d[1,]$Var1))` but I'm guessing it was a factor because you have something non numeric in the data.

Comment: @TylerRinker cool man, this actually works. I dump my data from a csv, and clean it beforehand, but yes, I guess probably some NA values make it non-numeric.

Comment: @YitongZhou maybe you should set ` stringsAsFactors= FALSE` in `read.csv`.

Comment: @TylerRinker: The Var[n] columns of the object returned from `as.data.frame.table` will always be factors. (Upvoted your comment since the first section was correct and helpful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as.data.frame` method for objects of class "table" returns the first column as a factor and (along with any other "marginal labels" columns) and only the last column as the numeric counts. See the help page for `?table` and look at the Value section. Tyler's recommendation to use the R-FAQ recommended `as.numeric(as.character(.))` conversion strategy is "standard R".

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function `table` turns the argument into a `factor` (type `table` into your console and you'll see the line `a <- factor(a, exclude=exclude)`.

The best solution is just to do what Tyler suggested to transform the results of `table` into `data.frame`

Comment: `table` did _not_ cause those values to become factors. It generally returns an object of class "table" which inherits from the "matrix" class. The code you are asking us to look at is building the names and bins of of the margins of the table-object.

Comment: Oh I see - so the `names` of the table are created through the code but ultimately of `class` character, and then `as.data.frame` converts them to `factor` by default?

Comment: Right. The dimnames of the matrix-like table-object get converted (as might be expected and is documented) to factor when the table is flattened, while the count entries remain numeric.