# Factors, levels, R syntax explanation

Tags: r, matrix, syntax, refactoring

I have a generic question of how to use and manipulate factors. In my work, R often coerces something into a factor because R does not allow different modes in a matrix, but in actuality I would prefer those columns to remain numeric.

When working with such factors I noticed:

- When you have two similar factors (e.g  all values between 1 and 5) in different columns, coercing the first column factor to a number by `as.numeric()` works fine. Coercing the second, third or fourth via as.numeric always adds 1 to every "factor". Why?
- There seems to be a difference between

  ```
  go$V4 <- as.double(go$V4)
  ```

  AND

  ```
  go[,4] <- as.numeric(levels(go[,4]))[go[,4]]
  ```

Assuming `as.double` and `as.numeric` are indeed largely identical, the difference is somewhere else but I don't get it.

Any syntax experts?

Comment: If you have different data types don't use a matrix and you won't face this problem. Use a list, data.frame or data.table instead. To coerce a factor to numeric, you need to make it a character first: `as.numeric(as.character(yourfactor))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement about  coercing to factor b/c of matrix requirements is simply wrong. (R matrices are incapable of holding factor variables.) Perhaps you are thinking of a data.frame. As the R FAQ says you need to use:

```
go$V4 <- as.numeric(as. character(go$V4))
```

If a numeric vector is concatenated (with `c()`) to any character vector, it is immediately coerced to "character" mode. If a column in a text field has non-numeric characters in it, the same thing happens on input.